# Fatal MaxEnt Error: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "-∞"

Tags: javascript, error, java, maxent

I'm trying to use MaxEnt to project species distribution. It worked to project probability the first time, but when I've put in the projection layers directory it comes up with this error and then crashes.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: is this `java` or `javascript`?